# nuxt.js Vuex Vuejs Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm new to Vuejs and Nuxt.js. I created Nuxt project while running project getting the error:

[image]

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Hi not sure if you have managed to resolve this.
If not you just have to restart your dev server to get Vue find the store.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Just shut down your IDE, restart it